# Running a systemd service without sudo privileges

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi, vlc, systemd

I have a PC that transmits log data over a TCP/IP socket to a Raspberry Pi. I have written a python server program that runs on the Pi, so that when certain keywords are encountered, it has to play the corresponding audio track - this is a gist of the problem I'm currently working on.

Now, I want this server program to run as soon as the Raspberry Pi boots up, and so I wrote a `systemd` service to enable that. Assuming my server code is named as `server.py`, my `service` file looks as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Python Server

[Service]
# Command to execute when the service is started
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /usr/bin/server.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I make this server program executable, and I don't face any issues to `start` and `enable` the service (verified by rebooting the Pi as well). Now, taking a step back, I play the audio track on the python server program using the following lines (a little snippet):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["cvlc", "~/Downloads/doors.wav"])
```

No errors here, all good. But when the service that runs the server program is started, when the specific keyword is encountered, the audio track does not play - it shows an error:

```
: [00005565470df480] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
: [0000556547157310] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $D
: [0000556547157310] main interface error: no suitable interface module
: [000055654700c570] main libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
: [0000556547101460] main interface error: no suitable interface module
: [000055654700c570] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
: [0000556547101460] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
: [00007f5f98c0b610] idummy demux: command `quit'
```

This same error shown above occurs when I try to play the audio from the command line with `sudo`, that is:

```
cvlc ~/Downloads/doors.wav
```

which led me to believe that if the service is enabled, then the whole python program corresponding to the service is run with sudo privileges automatically, even if I don't intend that to happen. I did a little bit of digging, but based on what I understand, to run the service, `sudo` privilege is necessary. I was not able to find a solution to run vlc with `sudo`, although I understand that ideally sudo privileges should not be given to something such as vlc. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the PulseAudio server runs under *your* user, not as `root`. The service you are starting runs as `root` and tries to connect to `root`'s PulseAudio server.

You can run specify which user/group to run the service as under the `[Service]` section with the `User` and `Group` directives.

You can also run the service as your user like this:

`$ systemctl start --user <service>.service`

Comment: Silly question, but does `Group` directive refer to something specifically, or what should it look like?

Comment: The `Group` directive is just a user group. For example, run `groups` as your user to see which groups it is a member of.

Answer (score 0):

may use polkit can helps here

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" && subject.isInGroup("anas") ) {
        var verb = action.lookup("verb");
        if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart" || verb == "enable" || verb == "disable" || verb == "mask" || verb == "unmask") {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
        }
    }
});
```